# PHP MySQL - Show Value on <Select></select> Form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I made 3 files (**detail.php**, **edit.php** and **editdata.php**)

**detail.php** shows the list of data from MySQL using `select * from table where id='$id` and it's working. But it's not working for my `<select>`. It still shows me the default value.

This is my *db connection*

```
<?php 
      include 'config.php';
      $id=$_GET['id'];
      $sqlTampil="select * from data_korban Where kasus_id=$id"; 
      $qryTampil=mysql_query($sqlTampil); 
      $dataTampil=mysql_fetch_array($qryTampil); 
      $data=mysql_fetch_array($qryTampil);
     ?>
```

Code for another form (It works)

```
<input type="DATE" name="tanggal" size="20" value="<?php echo $dataTampil['tanggal']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="namakorban" size="40" value="<?php echo $dataTampil['namakorban']; ?>">
```

The code for select form (not working) (*default value = Kota Mataram* and the Selected value is *Lombok Tengah*)

```
<select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten" value="<?php echo $dataTampil['kabupaten']; ?>">
<option value="Kota Mataram">Kota Mataram</option>
<option value="Lombok Barat">Lombok Barat</option>
<option value="Lombok Tengah">Lombok Tengah</option>
<option value="Lombok Timur">Lombok Timur</option>
<option value="Lombok Utara">Lombok Utara</option>
<option value="Sumbawa Besar">Sumbawa Besar</option>
<option value="Sumbawa Barat">Sumbawa Barat</option>
<option value="Kota Bima">Kota Bima</option>
<option value="Dompu">Dompu</option>
</select>
```

I'm a bit confuse on how to set values in select form.

Comment: <Select> doesn't have value tag. It will get its value depending on the option selected.

Comment: Please see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `value` attribute from your `<select>` element and use the `selected` attribute in the appropriate `<option>` element, for example...

```
<option value="Kota Mataram"
        <?= $dataTampil['kabupaten'] == 'Kota Mataram' ? 'selected' : '' ?>
>Kota Mataram</option>
```

You could streamline this using an array and `foreach` loop, eg

```
<select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten">
    <?php foreach (['Kota Mataram', 'Lombok Barat', 'Lombok Tengah' ... ] as $value) :
    $selected = $dataTampil['kabupaten'] == $value ? ' selected' : '';
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $value ?>"<?= $selected ?>>
        <?= $value ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```